# Opening a new activity with Simple adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adapter

I have codes like this.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "id"
            }, new int[] {
            R.id.titlee, R.id.idd});

    setListAdapter(adapter);      

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String food = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, Posts.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

when I try to open new activity with Intent it gave an error. Because simple adapter use `extends ListActivity` but `Intent i = new Intent(this, Posts.class);` needs a `extends Activity` how can open a new activity when I use a simple adapter

Comment: no ... `this` at this place is `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` implemantation(please learn java basics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Posts.class);
```

Pass `Activity` context to Intent first argument

Comment: ... you have enough reputation to mark this question as duplicate... why are you answering? for "free" reputation? not nice ...

Comment: @Selvin No it's not about Reputation. it's about the solution.

Comment: acting like this makes unnecessary noise in future searching results

Comment: @Selvin Sorry my friend!! I forget it.!!!!

Comment: also, if you are mark the question as duplicate, the comments with link appears under the question, so OP can easily find the solution ... so still i think its all about the reputation ...